# Mi aplicación no funciona en segundo plano [ANDROID]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Escribo por aquí porque he probado de todo y no se muy bien como solucionar esto.
He creado una aplicación para Android en Kotlin muy básica, la cual el único funcionamiento que tiene es enviar cada cierto tiempo (en bucle) unos valores mediante un método `POST` a una URL mediante `JSON` .
La aplicación funciona perfecta, hace lo que quiero, pero cada vez que bloquea el móvil donde lo estoy probando en `Android 11` o cambio de aplicación, su ejecución se para. La tengo que tener abierta todo el tiempo sin que se bloquee el dispositivo para que funcione, y la idea es que la aplicación se mantenga activa siempre.

Debido a que necesitaba que estuviera siempre activa, cambie toda la estructura para usar `ForegroundService` ya que se supone que este método es menos restrictivo a la hora de matar los procesos, por lo que lo cambie todo.
Logre hacer que todo funcionara bien, pero aun así, el proceso de enviar los valores mediante `POST` se pausa cuando se bloquea el terminal o se cambia de aplicación (y he comprobado que el `ForegroundService` se encuentra en ejecución ya que se me activa la notificación del servicio).

También he desactivado el control inteligente de batería del dispositivo donde lo estoy probando por si fuera eso, pero nada… ya no se que mas mirar.

Comment: Si no muestras el código es difícil ayudarte

Comment: Agrega más información a tu pregunta, el còdigo de tu servicio y la configuraciòn en el AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya funciona todo, he añadido android:foregroundServiceType a la etiqueta service de AndroidManifest.xml (la cual se me habia pasado poner) y parece que funciona, pero no se si se arreglo debido a esto o que se quedo algo en cache y al volver a compilar ya se arreglo (raro porque compile varias veces antes).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).